# Why encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom is not working for some component

Tags: angular

In the below demo code, `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` is working in a way I do not understand.

Scenario:

1. Go to `AppComponent` , Uncomment `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom`. The styling is passed on to all child components. Fine, comment it again.
2. Go to `Child2Component`,  Uncomment `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom`.  Nothing is rendered. Why ? I was expecting all **GrandChildComponents** to inherit the style (all `h1` as `red`) where as `Child2Component` should remain unaffected. Am I wrong ?

With `None` and `Emulated`, things are working as expected. The `Native` seems to be [deprecated as per the docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation#ShadowDom) . The table has strikedout the `Native`

[Here is the demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-izdfjn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

There is an active bug for angular and if you look at console errors you will see similar error from your attached demo app.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31135

Comment: They seem to be getting this as an error but their app (angular elements) seems to be working fine. Why is it not working in my case

Comment: Well it says this: Changing to:
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Emulated,
removes the error, but then the whole app is gone, blank screen.